# how to convert rgb to hex? almost there. 1% error colors

Tags: scripting, color

I am trying to get a hex value out of material color.
I find an reply here by @douripo:
[Get Hex triplet for color and real 256 RGB from diffuse Color using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95304/get-hex-triplet-for-color-and-real-256-rgb-from-diffuse-color-using-python)

it successfully converts most of the colors to hex correctly. except a few.
here is an example it does not convert right.

in blender, add a material to default cube and manually set its diffuse_color to hex 60590A (brown-ish yellow)

run below code in text editor, it would return 6059AA (purple-ish blue). could anyone check where went wrong? and hopefully a fix?

```
import bpy
import math

#code by : brecht - devtalk.blender.org
def to_hex(c):
    if c < 0.0031308:
        srgb = 0.0 if c < 0.0 else c * 12.92
    else:
        srgb = 1.055 * math.pow(c, 1.0 / 2.4) - 0.055

    return hex(max(min(int(srgb * 255 + 0.5), 255), 0))

def toHex(r,g,b):
    rgb = [r,g,b]
    result = ""
    i=0
    while i < 3:
        val = str(to_hex(rgb[i]))
        val = val[2:]
        if len(val) == 1:
            val += val
        result+=val
        i+=1
    return result

ob = bpy.context.object
color_inferior = ob.active_material.diffuse_color

a = toHex(color_inferior[0],color_inferior[1],color_inferior[2])

print (a)
```

Comment: 1% is a gross exaggeration:  with just integers for colors it would be `16 / 256` cubed or  less than one  ten thousands of one percent of all possible colors.... , lol. Good spot. IIRC there is another answer re this converting  both ways. ... actually prob less, 15 numerator since zero `00`  would have worked as expected too.

Comment: That's counting colors where every RGB value is wrong, It's more like 17% where at least one RGB value is wrong.

Comment: @scurest No doubt it's  OR _ie_  `3 * 15 / 256` .. not  AND never was good at stats

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue  occurs when   `str(to_hex(rgb[i]))[2:]`  returns a length 1 value, which is the case for  blue in example given "0xa".

```
        if len(val) == 1:
            val += val
```

incorrectly turning it into "aa" instead of "0a".  Using `val = "0" + val` will correct the issue.  Another option, used below, is  string formatting to convert an integer `i`  into a zero padded length 2 hex string `"%02x" % i`

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
def linear_to_srgb8(c):
    if c < 0.0031308:
        srgb = 0.0 if c < 0.0 else c * 12.92
    else:
        srgb = 1.055 * math.pow(c, 1.0 / 2.4) - 0.055
        
    if srgb > 1: srgb = 1

    return round(255*srgb)


def toHex(r, g, b):
    return "%02x%02x%02x" % (
        linear_to_srgb8(r),
        linear_to_srgb8(g),
        linear_to_srgb8(b),
    )
```

Comment: Fantastic !!! it works like a charm. thank you so very much for pointing it out and fixing it.